# Javascript dragleave runs only first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have drag and drop script, at first attempt it runs dragenter than dragleave, but after drop it stops working dragleave. Any suggestions?

```
var counter = 0; $('.bodierClass').bind({
dragenter: function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // needed for IE
    counter++;
    $('#filedrag').modal('show');
},
dragleave: function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter === 0) { 
        $('#filedrag').modal('hide');
    }
}});
```

Comment: `$('#filedrag').modal('hide');` this matters? I think we need html

Comment: it bootstrap modal, when dragenter run it will show modal when dragleave hide modal

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
$('.bodierClass').one("dragenter" ,function(ev) {
  console.log("dragenter")

  $('.bodierClass').one("mouseout", function() {
      console.log("dragleave")   
    })
});
```

**DEMO:**https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLMRJQ

Comment: mouse out not worked. i changed one("dragenter"...) and one("mouseout"...) to on("dragenter"...) and on("dragleave"...) it works, but when leaving slowly it recognized as dragenter and stops working att all